# C++14 operator << for stream insertion and enum class

Tags: c++, class, enums, nested, enum-class

I am writing a game in which there are 2 players, "BLACK" and "WHITE".

I have the following enum class:

```
enum class PlayerType
{
    BLACK, WHITE
};
```

I would like to write an ostream operator<< for this class. Here is my attempt:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const PlayerType& pt)
{
    if(pt == PlayerType::BLACK)
        os << "Black";

    return os;
}
```

However I get the following compiler error:

```
operator<< must take exactly 1 argument
```

I think the problem is that I am nesting the enum class, and operator<< inside another class; `class Player`.

Is there anything I can do about this without removing the enum from within this class?

Comment: Remove the function from that class.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything I can do about this without removing the enum from within this class?

If it makes sense, you can declare the operator as a `friend` of `Player`. This makes it a non-member. However, you need to ask yourself if friendship is really the relation you need between operator and class. If not, move the operator outside of the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

When declaring any of the binary operators as a non-`static` member they'll take one argument in addition to the implicit object pointed to by `this`. The object pointed to by `this` is always the left-hand argument of the binary operator and the declared argument is the right-hand argument. Operators with additional arguments are not legal.

Since the stream classes need to be on the left-hand of the `<<` operator you can't define the stream operators as non-`static` members. Making them non-member function is the only real option. Using a `friend` function to define the output operator still effectively declares a non-member function.